# Updates to Type A record set not reflecting in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I had 2 EC2 instances - one connected to `mydomain.com` and another connected to `dev.mydomain.com`

When `mydomain.com` instance went down because of some reason I changed the record set of `mydomain.com` to the public IP of second EC2 instance. The change was immediately reflected and `mydomain.com` started working fine.

After a few hours after fixing issues with the first EC2 server I reverted the IP address in the record set of `mydomain.com`. But this does not work. `mydomain.com` still points to the 2nd EC2 machine.

Can anybody suggest possible solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNS changes take time to propagate. Also, computers cache DNS responses, so checking changes can be difficult. The best advice is to wait, or to check it via a different computer.

You might want to use a service like https://cachecheck.opendns.com/ to check the resolution, or clear your cache before checking (in Windows, use `ipconfig /flushdns`).

Comment: It actually took some time to reflect. Now its working fine. We have switched to elastic IPs to avoid such problems in future.

Answer (score 3):

DNS records have a `ttl` or Time To Live. This means records are not refreshed from the central server until that TTL has expired.

You should look at using failover records in R53 :)